# I can't find any Quick Look cache data in macOS Mojave beta

Tags: macos, mojave

I'm using macOS Mojave beta and I'm trying to find out where Quick Look cache data is stored.

As of High Sierra, I found the Terminal command to open the path of Quick Look cache data:

```
open $TMPDIR/../C/com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache/
```

This is what it looks like:
[image: dd]

But when running Mojave beta, my Mac doesn't have any files in that path (I haven't cleared the cache at all and checked with `qlmanage -r enable`), I frequently used Quick Look though.

[image]

Quick Look works fine but I'd like to know why my Mac doesn't store cache data.

**UPDATE**

This is the output of command:

```
sudo lsof -c quicklookd
```

[image]

But I don't see anything in the directory via Finder.

```
/private/var/folders/ff/3m1y9syj5cd_vhjpgy0yy5c00000gn/C/com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache/
```

If I tried it through Terminal. It says the issue in terms of permission. I have completely no idea what this permission comes from:

```
~ (166) $cd /private/var/folders/ff/3m1y9syj5cd_vhjpgy0yy5c00000gn/C/com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache
cd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted

/private/var/folders/ff/3m1y9syj5cd_vhjpgy0yy5c00000gn/C (171) $ls -l | grep quicklook
ls: com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: You could try the Terminal command `sudo lsof -c quicklookd` (type your login password when asked) to list which paths `quicklookd` is using (make sure you first perform a query with Quick Look). The thumbnails path is probably included in the list.

Comment: @jaume  Thank you for response. 
The command you gave me does nothing. Please see the photo.

Comment: Have you performed a query before running the command (pressing Command-Space and typing something should suffice)? Otherwise `quicklookd` may not be running.

Comment: @jaume my apologies, I didn't look at your reply correctly. Now, I can see the result for lsof command. it looks it shows the path like $TMPDIR/../C/com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache but I see nothing there.. I updated the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot and your comments, apparently Mojave has changed the permissions of the thumbnail cache folder to make it "private". You can list its contents with `sudo ls -l /private/var/folders/ff/3m1y9syj5cd_vhjpgy0yy5c00000gn/C/com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache`. From `lsof`'s output I'd say you will see several files there.

Comment: @jaume Thank you for answering. I tried that but still got message like "Operation not permitted" I found that this problem comes from SIP. When I disabled it, I was able to access the cache file. I'm just curious if there is a way to access without disabling SIP..

Comment: Great you found out it is related to System Integrity Protection, that may be the reason you can't even list its contents with `sudo ls <path>`. I don't think you can circumvent SIP.

Comment: @jaume Thank you for editing :-) Sorry for my grammar.. It now got to be more looking clear.

Comment: I summarized the information in these comments in a short answer. Feel free to edit it or to add your own answer. You could then mark one of them as the accepted answer, if you think it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mojave, `quicklookd` stores the information in the same private folder hierarchy:

```
/private/var/folders/<id>/<random>/com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache
```

as in High Sierra.

To list the exact folder name used in Mojave (this procedure also works in High Sierra), open a Finder window, select a document or application, press <kbd>space</kbd> to fire up Quick Look, launch Terminal and run:

```
sudo lsof -c quicklookd
```

`lsof -c` displays which files and folders are in use by a specific process. 
The result will look similar to this (the red circle highlights the private folder):

[image]

The folder can't be accessed, neither by a standard user (even with `sudo`) nor by an administrator:
[image]

As you posted in your comment, the reason why you can't see its contents is because it is protected by [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899). That's new in Mojave.

Comment: That sucks. Is there no way to clear the thumbnail cache, then?

Comment: yes, `qlmanage -r cache`